# Почему программа не выводит результат

Tags: c#

такая проблема: нужна вывести Авто,вес прицепа которых больше 1500.

```
Console.WriteLine("Вывести грузовое авто с прицепом больше 1500 кг? ");
otvet = "";
otvet = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine();
if (otvet == "да") 
{

    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        trackercar[j].track_1500(ref j);
    }
}

public void show_track(int k2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Авто " + k2.ToString() + ": " + marka + "  " + model + "  " +
                                          countryrelease + "  " + color + "  " + price + "  " + trailer_weight);

}
public void track_1500(ref int j)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(trailer_weight[j]) >= 1500)
    {
        show_track(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуй `otvet.Equals("да")` в условии.

Comment: Какой смысл в присвоении переменной `otvet` значения пустой строки перед вызовом `ReadLine` и передаче по ссылке счетчика в `track_1500`?

Comment: Присвоение переменной пустой строки потому что перед этим еще есть функции с этой переменной и чтобы ее обнулить,а передача по ссылке для того чтобы выводился тот нужным элемент массива

Comment: Без содержимого массивов и даже без значения k не получится угадать, что именно у вас идет не так. Поставьте точку остановки (F9), на строке if (otvet == "да"), запустите программу по отладкой (F5), и пройдите по шагам (F11) проверяя значения переменных (можно просто мышкой в отладчике смотреть по наведению, или в окнах Auto / Watch).

Comment: И да, передача по ссылке не нужна. Она нужна только в случае, если метод track_1500 меняет значение j, и это изменение нужно вернуть наверх.